# Unity, Mesh zone breaking phenomenon when 'Agent Radius' of 'Navigation' is changed

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

If you use a number other than 0.3 for 'Agent Radius' in 'Navigation', the mesh area is broken as shown in the picture below.

The bottom on which the mesh is created is flat with 'plane'. However, it breaks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMQj9.jpg)

Comment: sometimes the navmesh shows with a cliping issue so, its not necessarily wrong its just the gizmo doesnt show it right